# Eclipse command line formatting others than java (IntelliJ Eclipse xhtml formatting diferences)

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, jsf, formatting

Is there any way to format code using Eclipse in command line? I found that there is an option using but only java files:

```
./eclipse -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -config config.xml formattingFile.java
```

I need to format files like xhtml because of differences between Eclipse and IntelliJ (Eclipse Code Formatter Plugin only works on Java files too).

Eclipse formatting (Web -> HTML files -> Editor -> Line width: 110):

```xml
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <!--equal for intellij and eclipse -->
    <h:outputText id="test_short" value="#{1veryLong.2veryLongValue.3veryLongValue.4veryLongValue.5veryLo}" />
    <!--break on intellij -->
    <h:outputText id="test_short" value="#{1veryLong.2veryLongValue.3veryLongValue.4veryLongValue.5veryLon}" />
    <!--break on intellij and eclipse-->
    <h:outputText id="test_short"
        value="#{1veryLong.2veryLongValue.3veryLongValue.4veryLongValue.5veryLongValue}" />

</ui:composition>
```

IntelliJ formatting (Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Hard wrap at 110 colums):

```xml
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <!--equal for intellij and eclipse -->
    <h:outputText id="test_short" value="#{1veryLong.2veryLongValue.3veryLongValue.4veryLongValue.5veryLo}" />
    <!--break on intellij -->
    <h:outputText id="test_short"
        value="#{1veryLong.2veryLongValue.3veryLongValue.4veryLongValue.5veryLon}" />
    <!--break on intellij and eclipse-->
    <h:outputText id="test_short"
        value="#{1veryLong.2veryLongValue.3veryLongValue.4veryLongValue.5veryLongValue}" />

</ui:composition>
```

**There's 2 important cases:**

1. IntelliJ format xhtml as XML, Eclipse as HTML
2. Eclipse count tab as 1 char, Intellij count tab as 4 chars

Comment: Hi welcome to the comunity. Please can you edit your question to be more clear. I'm assuming that you want to know how to format via command line and you already know how to do it via editor (and you are just showing that right?).

Comment: @ÒscarRaya i know only how to format java files. Problems are with other types. Like in example, i can't configure intellij like eclipse to format xhtml, so i try to use eclipse but try this in command line to make it faster and simpler.